# Training '\x00' s and TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str

Tags: python, string, split, path

I have a json file where I stored path to several files like this:

```
>> head test_data.json 
data/Benign/P_00004_LEFT_CC.tif
data/Benign/P_00004_LEFT_MLO.tif
data/Benign/P_00004_RIGHT_MLO.tif
data/Benign/P_00018_RIGHT_CC.tif
```

Now the problem is when I read the file in python and save each line in an array I have trailing `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00` at the end of line. I tried `str.rstrip()` and `str.rstrip('\n')` but had no luck.

[image]

This is causing problem when I try to check the existence of paths using `os.path.exists()` like following

```
if os.path.exists(path_list[0]):
       img1 = self.loader(path_list[0])
        ........
```

I am getting error at `os.path.exists()`

```
TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What about `rstrip('\x00')`?

Comment: Furthermore please next time copy-paste the code into the question (you can also add an *optional* image). That way it is easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rstrip('\x00')`, or you can use `rstrip('\x00\n')` to strip both `'\n'` and `\x00'` concurrently:

```
>>> s = 'data/Benign/P_00004_LEFT_CC.tif\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n'
>>> s.rstrip('\n\x00')
'data/Benign/P_00004_LEFT_CC.tif'
```

That being said, I would ask myself how NULL-characters occur in the file in the first place.

You can process the list of `path_list` in batch by using:

```
path_list = [item.rstrip('\n\x00') for item in path_list]
```

before using the `path_list` when processing the file names.